# Does soldier rank matter?

Tags: xenonauts

Occasionally my soldiers get promoted to the next higher rank. Does this have any in-game effect such as stat bonuses?

Comment: if this game remains faithful to the original x-com, higher rank only brings headaches in the form of bigger panic values when a high rank soldier dies.

Comment: "Where's Apone?!"

Answer (score 4):

It does, granted it only gives +2-4 basically across the board. There is more of a reward from training troops during combat such as weight penalties however.

Answer (score 0):

Only the first promotion from Private to Corporal gives a stat bonus of +2 to every stat. Receiving a medal gives the Xenonaut a stat bonus of +1 to Bravery. Otherwise stats [increase due to earning progress points](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/173081/23959) during combat from corresponding actions.